# How to use the VGA camera as a optical sensor?

Tags: image-processing, mobile, face-detection

I am designing an information kiosk which incorporates a mobile phone hidden inside the kiosk.
I wonder whether it would be possible to use the VGA camera of the phone as a sensor to detect when somebody is standing in front of the kiosk.

Which SW components (e.g. Java, APIs, bluetooth stack etc) would be required for a code to use the VGA camera for movement detection?

Answer (score 2):

Obvious choice is to use face detection. But you would have to calibrate this to ensure that the face detected is close enough to the kiosk. May be using the relative size of the face in the picture. This could be done using [opencv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) lib which is widely used. But as this kiosk would be deployed in places you would have little control of the lighting, there's a good chance of false positives and negatives. May be you also want to consider a proximity sensor in combination with face detection.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what platform is the information kiosk using the options would vary... But assuming there is linux somewhere underneath, you should take a look at [OpenCV library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/). And in case it is of any use - here's a link to [my funny experiment to get the 'nod-controlled interface' for reading the long web pages](http://bnpcs.blogspot.com/2009/05/nod-x11-linux-interface.html).

And speaking of false positives - or even worse - false negatives - in case of bad lighting or unusual angle the chances are pretty high. So you'd need to complement that by some fallback mechanism like onscreen button 'press here to start' which would be there by default, and then use the inactivity timeout alongside with the face detection to avoid having just one information input vector.

Another idea (depending on the light conditions), might be to measure the overall amount of light in the picture - natural light should be eliciting only slow changes, while the person walking close to the kiosk would cause rapid lighting change.

Answer (score 0):

In j2me (java for mobile phones), you can use the mmapi (mobile media api) to capture the camera screen.

Most phones support this.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew's suggestion on OpenCV is good. There are a lot of motion detection projects. BUT, I would suggest adding a cheap CMOS camera rather than the mobile phone camera.